# Access Object inside property call()?

Tags: javascript

Having a strange issue - for some reason, accessing the parent object inside a property using the `call()` method only works when it is returned inside a function.

Why am I not able to access MyObject in the second example, but I can in the first?

I need to get the second working as I don't want to constantly be calling functions inside loops as it's slow and looks bad.

**What I have right now:**

```
var MyObject = { 
   "selectorArray": ['[id*="example"]','[class*="example"]'],
   "all": function() {
      return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(MyObject.selectorArray.join())); 
   },
   "somemethod": function () {
             for (var i = 0; i < MyObject.all().length; i++) {
                   MyObject.all()[i] // do something etc
             }
    }
    .. I need to use all() in loops other methods also
}
```

**What I want** (faster and better looking)

```
var MyObject = { 
   "selectorArray": ['[id*="example"]','[class*="example"]'],
   "all": Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(MyObject.selectorArray.join())),
   "somemethod": function () {
             for (var i = 0; i < MyObject.all.length; i++) {
                   MyObject.all[i] // do something etc
             }
    }
    .. I need to use all in loops other methods also
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MyObject` doesn't exist while the object literal is being evaluated. You can't use `MyObject.anything` to define the value of `MyObject.all` in the literal, because you're referring to a property of an object that hasn't yet been created. Instead, you can pull the value you need out of the literal:

```
var selectorArray = ['[id*="example"]','[class*="example"]'];
var MyObject = { 
   "selectorArray": selectorArray,
   "all": Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(selectorArray.join())),
   "somemethod": function () {
             for (var i = 0; i < MyObject.all.length; i++) {
                   MyObject.all[i] // do something etc
             }
    }
    ...
};
```

Comment: Interesting - so how come it works inside methods then? are all methods in an object returned after the object has been initalised?

Comment: Because, when you create the object `"somemethod": function() { ... }` only sets the `somemethod` property to the function, but the the function isn't executed until the method is called. So, the reference in the method to `MyObject` isn't evaluated until the method is called.

Comment: @user2381114 It works inside methods, because, when the methods are actually needed and called, the object literal has been long evaluated and created. As a result, the code inside the methods has access to the actual object